# iOS: SharedCoreData Example Code (iCloud + CoreData) | How are changes merged

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I'm trying to adopt the WWDC 2012 example code for iCloud and CoreData ([link to github sample code](https://github.com/jab5990/TestCDiCloud)) and need some help understanding what's going on there.

I have a table view that takes its contents from a NSFetchedResultsController just like in the example. The NSFetchedResultsController is connected with the main NSManagedObjectContext from the CoreDataController provided by the example. Changes to entrys are synced from one device to another and it works like a charm. But there is no place where changes from iCloud are actually merged into the main context. I've seen a lot of examples where the NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification is used to merge the changes, but in this code that never happens.

But here is the strange thing: I take an object from the main context and hold it. If I receive the NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification I use the objectId and reload the object from the NSMangedObjectContext:

```
NSManagedObjectID* objectId = [myObject objectID];
NSManagedObject* theNewObject = [[_coreDataController mainThreadContext] objectWithID:objectId];
myObject = theNewObject;
```

But the object is not up to date. Even if I do a fetch with a predicate using a unique property of the object. But the table view with the NSFetchedResultsController shows the changes. What am I missing here?

EDIT 1 (After reading Tom's answer):

I added an observer for the `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification`:

```
- (void)iCloudupdate:(NSNotification*)note {
    NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [[CoreDataController sharedController] mainThreadContext];
    [moc performBlock:^{
        [moc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:note];
        [self refreshObject];
    }];
}
```

The method `refreshObject` uses the `NSManagedObjectID` to fetch the object from the main MOC, but it's still an old version.

Comment: Can you please help me out to solve this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718104/how-to-use-sample-code-of-core-data-with-icloud-session-227-in-wwdc-2012

Comment: I can't figure out what should I do first to use sample code. I can't use sample code from apple into my app.. I'm not a just newbie. I did same thing in iOS5 that using core data with iCloud. so help me please. Thanks.

Comment: What should I make change on the sample code first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be an iOS bug.  See this thread: http://devforums.apple.com/message/735512#735512

This fixed it for me:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
moc.stalenessInterval = 0;
```

This didn't help:

```
[moc refreshObject:myObject mergeChanges:YES];
```

Comment: In the meantime I could solve the problem as you mentioned, but still think that it doesn't feel right. However it's a solution, so I'll mark this as an answer!

Comment: I had the same problem on Mavericks too. Thus this problem is not limited to iOS. Setting stalenessInterval to 0 solved the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The lack of `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification` is a pretty significant omission from the SharedCoreData sample code. You definitely need to observe it, and the fact that you aren't doing so is directly related to not seeing updated values. If you were to quit the app and relaunch it, you'd probably get the new values you expect.

In the simplest case, you need to do two things when you receive this notification:

1. Call `-[NSManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification]` with the incoming change notification as the argument. This will notify your MOC about the new values. If you have unsaved changes in memory, they'll be merged with the incoming changes according to the MOC's merge policy (see the constants listed in the docs for `NSMergePolicy` for more detail on the options here).
2. Run the de-duplication process. The sample code *does* have a sample implementation of this. You'll need to look it over and see whether it's appropriate to your data model-- i.e. whether it actually detects duplicates correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The documentation says that the method mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification should be used with a NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification. I tried with the other "super long notification" you suggested and there is no error. So I guess you're right about that. But fetching the object from the MOC by its objectId still gives me the old version :(